# Does stochastic ordering for modulo $n$ random variables hold?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are said to be stochastically ordered $X\succeq Y$ if their distribution functions satisfy $F_Y(x)\geq F_X(x)$ for all $x$.

As a consequence of this argument, for stochastically ordered random variables $X_k$ and $Y_k$, one can write $$\sum X_k\succeq\sum Y_k$$

I am wondering about generalization of the same theory to modulo $n$ random variables. For example we have $X_1\succeq Y_1$, each are discrete and defined on $\{0,1,...,7\}$. We also have  $X\succeq Y$, and both are also defined on $\{0,1,...,7\}$. Now consider $$X_2=X_1+X \mod(8)$$ and $$Y_2=Y_1+Y \mod(8)$$

> $1.$ Can we say that $X_2\succeq Y_2$?
>
> $2. $Is there any textbook material about stochastic relations of modulo random variables?

**My solution** to $1.$ is that it is not true. Because, using coupling theory $X_1+X$ is a random variable which is larger than $Y_1+Y$ for all realizations. When we take the mod for all realizations, due to modulo operation not all realizations of $X_2$ will be larger than $Y_2$. This suggests that $X_2$ is either not stochastically larger than $Y_2$, or at least the coupling is gone.

I think the distribution of $X_2$ can be obtained by circularly convolving the pmfs of $X_1$ and $X$. The same goes for $Y_2$. I tried to make some examples and in all cases I found that $X_2\succeq Y_2$ was true.

**Link:**  Here is [the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2141590/x-1-and-x-2-stochastically-larger-than-y-1-and-y-2-implies-x-1x-2-sto) for the solution of non-modular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counterexample, using constant random variables. Let

$X = X_1 = 5$.

$Y = Y_1 = 2$.

Then $X \ge Y$ and $X_1\ge Y_1$, but $$X+X_1 \equiv 2\not\ge 4\equiv Y+Y_1 \mod (8)$$

I think it is in general pretty useless to talk about the ordering $\le$ on $\mathbb Z/(n)$ defined by $[x]<[y]$ when the smallest positive representative of $[x]$ is less than that of $[y]$. This is because it is not compatible with the group operation, in the sense that $a\le b$ does not implies $a+c\le b+c$.

Comment: $X+X_1=10$ it’s not $2$

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I meant my addition to be modulo $(8)$, I will clarify.

Comment: Yes that’s the same thing as mentioned in the question with coupling theory. But with constant random variables the order of distribution functions will be the easiest to see. Ok.